# R - programmatically detect NA columns and return string

Tags: r, if-statement, dplyr, na

I have this vector of eligible columns for my script

```
cols <- c("country", "phone", "car")
```

And this `dataframe`

```
test <-
  data.frame(
    id = c(1, 2, 3),
    country = c("us", NA, "uk"),
    phone = c(1, 1, NA),
    car = c(NA, 0, 1)
  )
```

The goal is to create a new column with the result, where the condition will be based only on columns present in cols variable. In case that all values for id are `NA`, then res should be string nothing, if some of them are not NA, then I need to this `colnames`, in case that all columns are not NA then result should be string all.

```
result <-
  data.frame(
    id = c(1, 2, 3),
    country = c("us", NA, NA),
    phone = c(1, 1, NA),
    car = c(NA, NA, NA),
    res = c("country, phone", "phone", "nothing")
  )
```

I can do it only via `case_when()` function

```
mutate(
    res = case_when(
      !is.na(country) & is.na(phone) & is.na(car)  ~ "country",
      T ~ "?"
    )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this in base R (rather than `dplyr`) using the code:

```
result$res <- apply(result[,cols],1, function(x){paste(cols[!is.na(x)], collapse=", ")})
result$res[results$res==""] <- "nothing"
```

Answer (score 0):

The data which you have shared is different (`test` and `result`). So we will start with `result` by removing the `res` column.

```
library(dplyr)
result$res <- NULL

result %>%
  mutate_all(as.character) %>%
  tidyr::pivot_longer(cols = cols) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(res = toString(name[!is.na(value)])) %>%
  type.convert() %>%
  left_join(res, by = 'id') %>%
   mutate(res = case_when(res == '' ~ 'nothing', 
                           stringr::str_count(result, ',') == 
                           (length(cols) - 1) ~ 'all',
                            TRUE ~ as.character(result)))


# A tibble: 3 x 5
#     id res            country phone car  
#  <dbl> <chr>          <fct>   <dbl> <lgl>
#1     1 country, phone us          1 NA   
#2     2 phone          NA          1 NA   
#3     3 nothing        NA         NA NA
```

We get the data in long format, get the column names which have non-NA value for each `ID`. We then change the `res` column to `"all"` or `"nothing"` if there are all or 0 matches respectively.